# Rounding problem

Tags: objective-c

I want to round a number to the nearest 'x'.  I tried

```
roundedNumber = x * floor(originalNumber / x + 0.5f);
```

and this seems to work in a calculator.  But in my cocoa app it is always rounding down to the nearest 60.

Am I making an obvious mistake?

originalNumber and roundedNumber are both NSIntegers.

Comment: If `x` is 60 this is exactly what I'd expect. You haven't told us what it is.

Comment: What type are originalNumber and x?  That could make a difference in the result.

Comment: sorry, 60 in this example.  You wouldn't expect it to round up when appropriate?

Comment: x and originalNumber are NSIntegers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSInteger is essentially an int/long, so try typecasting it to float:

```
roundedNumber = x * floor(float(originalNumber)/x + 0.5f);
```

Even better, use round():

```
roundedNumber = x * round(float(originalNumber)/x);
```

Answer (score 0):

try roundedNumber = x * floor((originalNumber / x) + 0.5f);
and roundedNumber = x * floor(originalNumber / (x + 0.5f));